# POST x-www urlencoded from cloud function (Firebase)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make an API request to Stripe API from a cloud firebase function using an HTTP POST request.

The parameters that have to be passed have to be on `x-www urlencoded` format.

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: 'Bearer sk_test_***',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
};

const params = 'amount=' + payment_intent.amount + '&currency=' + payment_intent.currency;
const CHARGE_URL = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents';

try {
    const snapshot: any = await Http.post(CHARGE_URL, params, httpOptions).toPromise();
    const intent: any = {
        id: snapshot.id,
        client_secret: snapshot.client_secret
    };
    await customerClassService.savePaymentIntent(requestId, intent);
    resp.status(200)
        .send(await Promise.all(intent));
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    resp.status(400)
        .send('An error occurred and will be solved ASAP.');
}
```

But it doesn't work can anyone help me

Comment: Can you please let me know the angular Version you are using ?

Comment: It's a cloud funtion for firebase 
So node 8 as engine
"typescript": "^3.2.2"

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In Vue I'd instantiate a `FomData` type with the post parameters which I'd then put in the `body` of the request. But typescript doesn't appear to recognise the `FormData` type.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get mine working using the `request-promise` library https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');

request.post(uri, {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        form: {
            "param1": "param1",
            "param2": "param2"
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .then(body =>{
        return body;
    });
```